# Improving performance when working with geodata in R

Tags: r, maps, geospatial, geo

[image]

I wrote the following script to produce the raw data for plotting the above map. The problem is, for 550,000 data points, this takes about 2 hours to run on a relatively powerful machine. I'm new to R, however, and I'm wondering if there are any optimized functions I can take advantage of?

The basic idea is that, given a set of geospatial data, you split the set into 200 rows, and split each row into a bunch of squares. You then calculate the total of a value in each square in a row. The approach I've taken below is to take the "upper left" point of a square, calculate the latitude/longitude of edges of the square, and exclude all points not in those bounds, and then sum what remains. Is there a better way without using a solution like PostGIS?

```
all.data <- read.csv("FrederictonPropertyTaxDiffCleanedv3.csv", header=TRUE, 
stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
all.data$X <- as.numeric(all.data$X)
all.data$Y <- as.numeric(all.data$Y)

startEnd <- function(lats, lngs) {
  # Find the "upper left" (NW) and "bottom right" (SE) coordinates of a set of data.
  #
  # Args:
  #  lats: A list of latitude coordinates
  #  lngs: A list of longitude coordinates
  #
  # Returns: 
  #   A list of values corresponding to the northwest-most and southeast-most coordinates

  # Convert to real number and remove NA values
  lats <- na.omit(as.numeric(lats))
  lngs <- na.omit(as.numeric(lngs))

  topLat <- max(lats)
  topLng <- min(lngs)
  botLat <- min(lats)
  botLng <- max(lngs)

  return(c(topLat, topLng, botLat, botLng))
}

startEndVals <- startEnd(all.data$Y, all.data$X)
startLat <- startEndVals[1]
endLat <- startEndVals[3]
startLng <- startEndVals[2]
endLng <- startEndVals[4]

num_intervals = 200.0
interval <- (startEndVals[1] - startEndVals[3]) / num_intervals

# testLng <- -66.6462379307115
# testLat <- 45.9581234392

# Prepare the data to be sent in
data <- all.data[,c("Y", "X", "levy2014_ha")]

sumInsideSquare <- function(pointLat, pointLng, interval, data) {
  # Sum all the values that fall within a square on a map given a point,
  # an interval of the map, and data that contains lat, lng and the values
  # of interest

  colnames(data) <- c("lat", "lng", "value")

  # Data east of point
  data <- data[data$lng > pointLng,] 
  # Data west of point + interval
  data <- data[data$lng < pointLng + interval,] 
  # Data north of point + interval (down)
  data <- data[data$lat > pointLat - interval,]
  # Data south of point
  data <- data[data$lat < pointLat, ]

  # Clean remaining data
  data <- na.omit(data)
  return(sum(data$value))
}

# Debugging
# squareSumTemp <- sumInsideSquare(testLat, testLng, interval, data)

# Given a start longitude and an end longitude, calculate an array of values
# corresponding to the sums for that latitude

calcSumLat <- function(startLng, endLng, lat, interval, data) {
  row <- c()
  lng <- startLng
  while (lng < endLng) {
    row <- c(row, sumInsideSquare(lat, lng, interval, data))
    lng <- lng + interval
  }
  return(row)
}

# Debugging
# rowTemp <- calcSumLat(startLng, endLng, testLat, interval, data)
# write.csv(rowTemp, file = "Temp.csv", row.names = FALSE)

# Get each line of data to plot
lat <- startLat
rowCount <- 1
all.sums <- list()
while (lat > endLat) {
  col <- calcSumLat(startLng, endLng, lat, interval, data)
  all.sums[[as.character(rowCount)]] <- col
  lat <- lat - interval
  rowCount <- rowCount + 1
}

# Convert to data frame
all.sums.frame <- data.frame(all.sums)

# Save to disk so I don't have to run it again
write.csv(all.sums.frame, file = "Levy2014Sums200.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: have you tried to profile your code using `Rprof` to find out where it is taking the most time?

Comment: Didn't know about RProf until now - will take a look at it!

Comment: Using RProf it's clear that the bottleneck is in the sumInsideSquares function. I've re-written the function so that all the dataFrame segmenting happens on a single line, and that cut the time in half. Still takes a long time to run, however, so I'll need to optimize it quite a bit further. I may start looking into multi-threading in R as this would be a prime candidate for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up finding a solution to this myself. The key to it was using the foreach package with the doParallel package so it could take advantage of all the cores on my computer. There is a great guide on it here: http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-brief-foray-into-parallel-processing-with-r/